# how to apply multiple conditions and append to the same table in one dataframe in pyspark and sql

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do this loop with week by week reduction. if the id and class_gp combo already appear in the previous week, then those combinations will remove for the current week/future week.

The data frame looks like this

```
df1: 
ID  Week_ID    class_gp  school_nm
 1  20200101    A          101
 1  20200101    B          101
 1  20200107    A          101
 1  20200107    B          101
 1  20200107    C          101
 1  20200114    B          101
 1  20200114    D          101
 1  20200121    B          101
 1  20200121    D          101
 1  20200121    E          101
```

The ideal output should look like this:

```
ID  Week_ID    class_gp  school_nm
 1  20200101    A          101
 1  20200101    B          101
 1  20200107    C          101
 1  20200114    D          101
 1  20200121    E          101
```

I am not very good with for loop, so I used the most stupid way by creating data frame for each week, then join them all.

## remove week1's id and class_gp combo for the rest of weeks

```
t1 = df1.where("week_id = '20200101'")

df2 = df1.join(t1,
    [df1.id == t1.id,df1.class_gp == t1.class_gp], 
    how='left_anti')
```

## remove week2's id and class_gp combo for the rest of weeks

```
t2 = df2.where("week_id= '20200107'")

df3 = df2.join(t2,
    [df2.id == t2.id,df2.class_gp == t2.class_gp], 
    how='left_anti'
)....
```

and create all 18 weeks like that.

but creating so much data frame and running like that make it really really slow.

I wonder is there an easy way to create a single data frame look like the ideal output.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a window function to achieve it:

`val windowSpec=Window.partitionBy("class","school").orderBy("week")`

and then apply a row_number function to the window and select the row with row=1 like below
`scala> school.withColumn("row", row_number().over(windowSpec)).where("row=1").orderBy("week","class").drop("row").show(false)`

```
+---+--------+-----+------+
|id |week    |class|school|
+---+--------+-----+------+
|1  |20200101|A    |101   |
|1  |20200101|B    |101   |
|1  |20200107|C    |101   |
|1  |20200114|D    |101   |
|1  |20200121|E    |101   |
+---+--------+-----+------+
```

Comment: I used .partitionBy("class","ID") with row number. it works! thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You neeed just 2 lines of Python code

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['Week_ID'], ascending=True)
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','class_gp'], keep='first')
```